# MYSQLI Fetch results from table: Display all users (but display deluxe and premium users first)?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a table in my database called user_data.
I want to select all rows of data from this table, where the user's advert_status is 'Active'.

However, there is also a column called advert_type in this table. The enum values of this are:

```
Deluxe, Premium and Basic.
```

I want to execute a MYSQLI query and list all users in the table where their advert_status is active. But i want to list deluxe users, then premium users and basic users - in that order.

Desired Result:

```
Deluxe User 1
Deluxe User 2
Deluxe User 3
Premium User 1
Premium User 2
Basic User 1
Basic User 2
```

Here's what i've tried.

```
$variable = $_GET['r'];
             if($variable == '0') {
             $query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM user_data WHERE advert_status = 'Active' ORDER BY advert_type");
```

This doesn't do the job. Please can someone show me how to achieve my desired result? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us some sample data so we can see the structure.  Likely, the `ORDER BY` clause is sorting properly, but your expectation of how it is sorting may be misconstrued.  Are the values numeric, with `0` representing Deluxe? Are they alphanumeric, with the value `deluxe` or similar?

Comment: @D.N. as the question states, there is a column called advert_type with enum values set out as 'Deluxe', 'Premium' and 'Basic'. This is the structure / layout of the table column.

Comment: So for your desired results from the duplicate I flagged, `ORDER BY FIELD(advert_type, "Deluxe", "Premium", "Basic")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `order by case when` to fulfill your requirement:

```
 SELECT * FROM user_data 
 WHERE advert_status = 'Active' 
 ORDER BY
    Case when advert_type = "Deluxe" then 1
         when advert_type = "Premium" then 2
         else 3 end asc
```

Comment: For an alternative comparison syntax you can use `CASE advert_type WHEN "Deluxe" THEN 1 WHEN "Premium" THEN 2 ELSE 3 END ASC` However using CASE WHEN for sorting is typically known to be slow.